# Mac Osx require at least 40gb of free space to install Windows with Bootcamp, but I have 70gb free!

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, disk-utility, windows

[image]

I don't understand why my macbook pro don't allow me to partitioning my hard drive to install windows 10.. It advice me that require at least 40gb when I have free around 70gb..  why this happen?!

Thank you.

Comment: it shows you have 49GB free space, where do you see 70 ?

Comment: in the finder status

Comment: anyway I have deleted all, created two partition from the recovery disk utility and windows installation now works without bootcamp